# Carrier furnace blower doesn't kick up to high

Tags: blower, carrier, circuit

I have two Carrier furnaces in my home.  One is 100btu the other is 80btu  they use the same the mother board. I have an outdoor wood boiler that heats our house and the furnaces are only use for back upbeat mainly used as blowers to distribute the heat.  In this situation i want the blower fan to be on High speed to get the heat distributed. Both boards toggle switches are set identical for high speed fan  - one  works perfect the other blows on low only.  so for a test i switched the boards and now the other one works on high and the one that was working only blows on low.  Ok so I ordered a used board on eBay put it in anti only runs only - what are the chances of having two boards with the same problem.  What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to SE.  Please re-read and edit your post, some of it is not understandable. We stand by to help.

Comment: are the two original boards the same?

Comment: A double take on the sizes would be a good idea probably 100k btu , the model numbers are missing, if the same brand simple controls are often the same the wiring may be interlocked we don’t know from the info provided.